# SUMPRODUCT Circular error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble with a simple excel formula. Here is a basic example :

[image]

I'm trying to sum all cells in B4:C7 when column A is not equal to B. If I set this formula in D1 for example this works well.

However If the formula is within the range B4:C7 on a line where column A is equal to B I get a circular error. The problem is there is no way my formula takes its own cell as it is on a line which colA = B. Excel calculates 0 as a result.

I know this example look silly. In my real problem all lines with A in col A won't execute the sumproduct because of various If conditions.

**UPDATE**

Here is a more precise example. The second tab displays what is correct. The formula is the same except for the ranges of the sumproduct that start from the line under the current one.

The formula is checking if some actual data was realized on the following month so as to start amortizing the budget after the last realized month.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the formula inside the region you want to sum up?

Comment: I'm gonna upload a more precise example

Comment: @Lich4r In which cell are you trying to put this formula ?